# monotonicity of nonnegative function under a certain condition

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ be a $C^{1}((0,\infty))\cap C([0,\infty))$ function.

Assume $f'(0)\geq f(0)>0$ and I want to show that
\begin{equation*}
\forall t>0,\, f'(t)\geq f(0) \, (>0)
\end{equation*}

My attempt so far is to use a contradiction argument.
Suppose the conclusion does not hold, then we have $t_{0}\in(0,\infty)$ s.t. $f'(t_{0})< f(0)$.
Moreover, I also know:

1. There exists $t_{1}\in(0,t_{0})$ s.t. $f(t_{1})=f(0)$.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you very much!

I think the difficulty comes from the fact that we only know the behavior of $f$ at $t=0$ but we need to obtain the information of $f'$ at any given point $t\in[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to prove is not correct. For example, There exist smooth (infinitely differentiable functions) non-negative $f$ such that $f(t)=1+t-t^{2}$ for $t$ near $0$.  Such an $f$ satisfies the hypothesis but $f'(t)=1-2t <0<f(0)$ for all $t>0$ near $0$.

An explicit construction of a $C^{1}$ function which satisfies the hypothesis but not the conclusion : $f(x)=1-x+x^{2}$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $f(x)= x+(x-1)^{2}$ for $x>1$.

Comment: Thank you very much to show me a counter example!

Actually, I was trying to show that if a function satisfies $f'\geq f^{p} - C$ for some constant $C>0$, $f(0)>C^{\frac{1}{p}}$, and $f\geq0$ in $[0,\infty)$, then $f'\geq f^{p} - C$ for any $t>0$...

Apparently, I need to find another way... do you have a good advice for the problem above?

Comment: I am sorry to not write it clearly... I meant $f'(0)\geq (f(0))^{p} - C >0$... basically, I want to extend the positivity of $f'$ at $t=0$ to all $t\in[0,\infty)$. 
Is this false?

Thank you for your valuable advice and discussion!

Comment: Yes it is false. It is not possible to conclude anything about $f'(t)$ for $t >0$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

However, I just realized that the counter example you gave me did not satisfy the assumption $f:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$. But, it was helpful for me, thanks!

Comment: I have now given a valid example.